# Observable<List<Object>> cannot be converted to Observable<List<Anime>>

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting the error "incompatible types: `Observable<List<Object>>` cannot be converted to `Observable<List<Anime>>`"

```
public Observable<List<Anime>> getOnlyAnimeObservable() {
    List onlyAnimeList = getOnlyAnimeList();
    if (onlyAnimeList == null) {
        return Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());  //Required <List<Class>> But Found <List<Object>>
    }
    return Observable.just(onlyAnimeList); //Required <List<Class>> But Found <List>
}
```

If I change `public Observable<List<List<Anime>> getOnlyAnimeObservable()` to

```
public Observable<List<Object>> getOnlyAnimeObservable()
```

> **return Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());** error solved but **return Observable.just(onlyAnimeList);** still shows error

At the same time if I change `public Observable<List<List<Anime>> getOnlyAnimeObservable()` to `public Observable<List> getOnlyAnimeObservable()`

> **return Observable.just(onlyAnimeList);** error solved but **return Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());** shows error.

Comment: Add some code. How you are doing this. What is this "Anime" ?

Comment: Anime is a class and here's the link to it https://pastebin.com/6YXMWEZr. I'm getting error in this class https://pastebin.com/6HNKfX73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of `Collections.emptyList()` returns `List<Object>`. Try this code:

```
List<Anime> list = Collections.emptyList();
return Observable.just(list);
```

`getOnlyAnimeList` method also should return `List<Anime>` type. So full code should be:

```
 public Observable<List<Anime>> getOnlyAnimeObservable() {
    List<Anime> onlyAnimeList = getOnlyAnimeList();
    if (onlyAnimeList == null) {
        List<Anime> list = Collections.emptyList();
        return Observable.just(list);
    }
    return Observable.just(onlyAnimeList);
 }
```

We can simplify everything:

```
public Observable<List<Anime>> getOnlyAnimeObservable() {
    List<Anime> list = getOnlyAnimeList();
    if (list == null) {
        list = Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return Observable.just(list);
}
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Mate. You're god send person to save my time :)

Comment: Hello mate, can you help me to find out the solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579870/class-not-found-exception-when-using-multidex