# Class not found exception when using Multidex

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

So my problem is I'm getting Class not found error while running the app on my device.

```
"io.tutorial.app.App" class not found at the path io.tutorial.app
```

Actually the class App.java is present at that path and also my class is extending `MultiDexApplication` .

What I found so far is two dex files have generated in the built apk namely classes.dex and classes2.dex. The weird thing is the package "io.tutorial.app" is present at both dex files (I think this is the issue). There's no classes present at the "io.tutorial.app" package in the **classes2.dex** file but all my classes are present in **classes.dex** file under the same package "io.tutorial.app". Please help me to find a solution to this.

**Manifest:**

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app"
    android:name="io.tutorial.app.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarFullScreen"
        android:name=".ui.activity.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Gradle:app**

https://pastebin.com/JpkRZY1G

**App Class:**

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {
@Inject
Cache cache;

public void onCreate() {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    super.onCreate();
    initRemoteConfig();
    Injector.getInstance().init(this);
    Injector.getInstance().appComponent().inject(this);
    initFabric();
    initRealm();
    initPicasso();
    initRemoteConfig();
    initAds();
    initOneSignal();
}
```

Comment: Try to disable instant run, also if it didn't help please add your manifest and your gradle file.

Comment: @BelbaharRaouf added manifest and gradle code. Please check.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I tried all those things.

Comment: you have added the `multidex` library in two versions; remove the `1.0.2` version ...even if not a duplicate; this is a minor typographical error.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I forgot to remove v1.0.2. I just added it. Lemme remove it and test.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Still same problem. Also I noticed another error on logcat which is Failed to open dex files from path because: Failure to verify dex file : Duplicate interface: 'Lio/realm/RealmProxyInterface'

Comment: @NithisKumar that might be related to `apply plugin: "realm-android"`. or any of these `RC` versions there, which are not stable (don't expect any of them to work as expected). also verify that `kapt` annotation processors (which are possibly not even required anymore).

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes now I solved that by updating realm plugin version but main issue App class not found still exists. I asked this to my friends, they don't have solution but all of them doubting the package present at both dex files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have that `@Inject` annotation under suspicion - or the use of `Injector`.

try to use `MultiDex.install()` instead:

```
public class App extends Application {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/tutorial/app/di/module/AppModule;
        at io.tutorial.app.di.Injector.init(Injector.java:45)
        at io.tutorial.app.App.onCreate(App.java:37) getting this error now